# Как сгруппировать эти функции в extension UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uibutton

Всем привет! Может кто-нибудь помочь разобраться? У меня имеются такие функции, как мне их сгруппировать и сделать на их основе расширение для  UIButton?

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // saddasd dsad dsad asdas
    let path = customPath()
    path.lineWidth = 3
    path.stroke()    
}

@objc func likeTap() {
    (0...10).forEach { (_)  in

        generateAnimationView()    
    }
}

func generateAnimationView() {
    let image = drand48() > 0.5 ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "money"): #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bravos")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

    let demision = 20+drand48()*10
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: demision, height:demision)

    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.path = customPath().cgPath
    animation.duration = 2 * drand48() * 3
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    let nameString = kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: nameString)
    imageView.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    contentView.addSubview(imageView)
}

 func customPath()->UIBezierPath {

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to:CGPoint(x:bravoBtn.layer.position.x, y: bravoBtn.layer.position.y))
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: -100, y: -100)
    let randomYShift = 100+drand48()*300
    let controlP1 = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 200-randomYShift)
    let controlP2 = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100+randomYShift)

    path.addCurve(to: endPoint, controlPoint1: controlP1, controlPoint2: controlP2)
    return path
}
```

Чтобы сделать `sender.likeTap()`.
Вот мой весь код :

```
import UIKit

class CustomSoccerHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    var clickBravisso: Soccer?
    @IBOutlet weak var bravoBtn: UIButton!{
        didSet {
            bravoBtn.layer.cornerRadius = bravoBtn.frame.size.width/2
            bravoBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
            bravoBtn.layer.borderWidth = 2
            bravoBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var countBravo: UILabel!
    @IBAction func likeBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

      // функция дрожания
        sender.flash()
        **чтоб тут сделать sender.likeTap()**


        if var clikBravo = clickBravisso?.bravissimo   {
            print("clikBravo")
            clikBravo += 1
            clickBravisso!.setObject(clikBravo, forKey: "bravissimo")
            clickBravisso!.saveInBackground()
            countBravo.text = "\(clikBravo)"
        } else {
            fatalError("clikBravo is null")
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var nameHeader: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageHeader: UIImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        bravoBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(likeBtn(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно для удобства я озаглавливаю группу функций в расширении, Вы можете тоже это сделать вот так:

```
private typealias ButtonAnimation = UIButton
```

Затем уже может следовать код самого расширения. В Вашем случае он может быть таким (Swift 4):

```
extension ButtonAnimation {

    override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // saddasd dsad dsad asdas
        let path = customPath()
        path.lineWidth = 3
        path.stroke()
    }

    func likeTap(contentView:UIView) {
        (0...10).forEach { (_)  in

            generateAnimationView(contentView:contentView)
        }
    }

    func generateAnimationView(contentView:UIView) {

        let image = drand48() > 0.5 ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "money"): #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bravos")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

        let demision = 20+drand48()*10
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: demision, height:demision)

        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.path = customPath().cgPath
        animation.duration = 2 * drand48() * 3
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        let nameString = kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: nameString)
        imageView.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    func customPath()->UIBezierPath {

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to:CGPoint(x:self.layer.position.x, y: self.layer.position.y))
        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: -100, y: -100)
        let randomYShift = 100+drand48()*300
        let controlP1 = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 200-randomYShift)
        let controlP2 = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100+randomYShift)

        path.addCurve(to: endPoint, controlPoint1: controlP1, controlPoint2: controlP2)
        return path
    }
}
```

И сразу несколько замечаний по коду. Лично я стараюсь избегать переопределения методов в расширениях, ибо возможно это только для классов Objective-C, мы же с Вами программируем на Swift и должны соблюдать правила данного языка. То есть я бы весь приведённый код скорее всего добавил бы в потомка `UIButton`, но так как мы пытаемся чинить Ваш код, то я лишь добавил `open`, чтобы сигнатура переопределяемого метода совпадала с Вашей.

У функции `likeTap` я убрал модификатор `@objc`, потому что он там не нужен. Вы же всё-равно вызывает данную функцию из кода на языке Swift. И ещё я добавил в неё дополнительный параметр-ссылку на `contentView` Вашего колонтитула (потому что кнопка не в курсе, что её будут использовать именно там, а не, скажем, в обычном `UIView`). Аналогичный параметр теперь будет и у `generateAnimationView`.

В функции `customPath` я заменил `bravoBtn` на `self`, я думаю я правильно понял Вашу идею.

Comment: Да. Роман Вы все правильно меня поняли))), но я блин сглупил.Можно было просто в функции action , вызвать функцию likeTap(). и все сработало))))).Я блин велосипед сложный сочинял.

Comment: Задумка хорошая, файлы с кодом всегда должны быть маленькими (строк по 300 максимум), поэтому все функции для работы с анимацией кнопки можно было куда-нибудь вынести - в новый класс-потомок UIButton или в расширение. Вы выбрали второй вариант, но это лишь дело вкуса, Вы на правильном пути.

Comment: Спасибо ))))...